# Why does my question not appear in the default (interesting) list?

Tags: discussion

Why would my SO question (which has a tag that is under my favourites) not be contained in the default "interesting" list?

It's had very low viewing numbers and I'm wondering it's being excluded from the list for everybody?   (To be honest, it's probably more to do with the standard of my title - people are probably just ignoring it!)

It is visible if you list posts based on the tags.

I'm in two minds about linking to the question, because I don't want to artificially inflate the views off the back of this post.

Comment: The interesting list has a life of its own, its best not to reason why

Comment: @RichardTingle The full formula is public...there's no need to guess why.

Comment: @Servy The entire universe is based on perhaps 20 rules, doesn't mean its behaviour is easy to predict

Comment: @RichardTingle If you actually knew what those rules were, and knew the current values of all of the parameters to those formulas then yes it would.  We nether know those rules, nor all information that would need to be supplied to them for them to work.  However, for the case of this particular question, we *do* know the formula, and we *do* know the values for all of the parameters to those functions, with the exception of the result of the RNG, which is the only unknown.

Comment: Thanks both (in particular @Servy). The formula is a bit much for my little brain to cope with, so I will just accept that it's well out of my hands.

Comment: @Servy I feel we are taking this a little seriously, my point is simply that systems with simple rules can have complicated outcomes. In this case other posts are critical and while the overall rules are known **the rules as to if a particular post will be shown change second by second**

Comment: In simple terms - The interesting list is for questions other users find interesting, that you may also find interesting. Since your question "had very low viewing numbers", it does not classify as such.

Comment: Sorry @Dukeling, but wouldn't that mean **every** question submitted would be instantly in the same situation, as they all start with 1 view?

Comment: @freefaller Well, 'interesting' isn't the only list, I for one mainly look at the 'newest' list. And then there's related questions, and actually looking for an answer to a question, and a whole bunch of other ways to get to a question to increase its views and votes to move it up on the interesting list.

Comment: @freefaller You should actually look at the algorithm a bit, just to see what has a positive and negative influence.  More views *decrease* the ranking.  Less views *increase* the ranking.